# How to loop through multiple array inside main array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

This is what I'm doing currently:

```
var Messages = function(data) {

    //dont change the order variable initialized
    var total = data.totalmessages;
    var data = data.messages;
    var counter = data.length;
    var mappedData = [];
    var attachment = [];
    var location = [];
    var id = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

        //attachment
         if (data[i].attachments.length > 0) {

            for (var j = 0; j < data[i].attachments.length; j++) {

                id = data[i].id;
                if (data[i].id == id) {

                    attachment.push({

                    'fileId': data[i].attachments[j].id,
                    'filename':data[i].attachments[j].name,
                    'messageId': data[i].id
                   });
                }

            }

         }

         //location

          if (data[i].locations.length > 0) {

            for (var k = 0; k < data[i].locations.length; k++) {

                id = data[i].id;

                if (data[i].id == id) {

                    location.push({

                    'locationId': data[i].locations[k].id,
                    'add':data[i].locations[k].add,
                    'messageId': data[i].id
                   });
                }
            }

          }

            mappedData.push({

                'id': data[i].id,
                'name': data[i].name,
                'attachment': attachment,
                'location': location
            });


    }

    var obj = {

        "template": config.templates.messagesBody,
        "data": mappedData,
        "totalItem": total
    }

    return obj;

};
```

What's happening above is, I'm looping through messages for a conversation. Inside the message, there might be attachment and location for some of the messages.

I can go through messages correctly which is the main array. But I don't know how to loop through attachment and location for specific message. In the above method, say I have 5 messages. Only 2 of it has attachment or location. When I finally make up the object consist of the messages(`return obj`), all of the messages has attachment and location.

Comment: Reset `attachment = []` and `location = []` inside the first `for` loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, so easy a fix. I was so dumb for not aware of this..Thanks a million